# Year range in bibliography with Biber

Tags: biblatex, biber

Given a bibliography entry with a year range, Biber produces the following warning:

> WARN - year field '1991--2007' in entry 'someRef' is not an integer -
>   this will probably not sort properly.

Is there a proper way to specify a year range?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@TECHREPORT{someRef,
    author = {John D. McCalpin},
    title = {{STREAM: Sustainable Memory Bandwidth in High Performance Computers}},
    institution = {University of Virginia},
    year = {1991--2007},
    address = {Charlottesville, Virginia},
    url = {http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
    \cite{someRef}
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `year` field should only ever contain a (four-digit) year. For fancy things like date ranges or full dates you should use the `date` field, which accepts ISO8601 input (see §2.3.8 *Date and Time Specifications*, esp. Tables 3, 4 and 5 of the [`biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

In your case that means that you need

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@TECHREPORT{someRef,
  author      = {John D. McCalpin},
  title       = {{STREAM}: Sustainable Memory Bandwidth in High Performance Computers},
  institution = {University of Virginia},
  date        = {1991/2007},
  address     = {Charlottesville, Virginia},
  url         = {http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/}
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  \cite{someRef}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: John D. McCalpin. STREAM: Sustainable Memory Bandwidth in High Performance Computers. Tech. rep. Charlottesville, Virginia: University of Virginia, 1991–2007. url: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/stream/.]

Comment: I am not sure how appropriate the biblatex tag is, I was attempting the solution from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121511/19326, which led to my awkward comment since I was convinced the year field should work. Assuming that answer is correct it works with biblatex but _not_ with biber. Not sure what the appropriate way is to communicate my concerns regarding an edit. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @ted Well, Biber can only be used with `biblatex`, so in a way `biblatex` is more relevant than the generic 'biblliographies' tag. If you feel strongly about it, you can always click roll back and undo my edit. I won't fight about that. (But maybe you are slightly confused about the difference between BibTeX and `biblatex` notice the `la` in the second one.)